# Suddenly, No module named models

Tags: python, django

I have a project with 3 apps, called projects, specimens and tests. This was working fine until I made a change (I don't remember what). After that, Django throws `ImportError: No module named models.` I can't imagine what is the problem because I think I have all well referenced and organized.

This is my error:

```
ImportError at /

No module named models

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.5.5
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named models

Exception Location:     /home/david/mysqldb/dev/mysqldb/teams_db/specimens/views.py in <module>, line 11
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.5
```

and this is my Traceback:

```
/home/david/mysqldb/dev/mysqldb/teams_db/teams_db/urls.py in <module>

        (r'^specimens/', include('specimens.urls')),

▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py in include

            urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)

▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module

        __import__(name)

▶ Local vars
/home/david/mysqldb/dev/mysqldb/teams_db/specimens/urls.py in <module>

    from views import new_specimen, list_specimens, info_specimen

▶ Local vars
/home/david/mysqldb/dev/mysqldb/teams_db/specimens/views.py in <module>

    from tests.models import Test

▶ Local vars
```

Inside the app `tests` I have the class Test, the one that is causing the error. This is the function that throws the error (specimens.views):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect,\
                        HttpResponseForbidden, HttpResponseBadRequest,\
                        HttpResponseServerError
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from forms import SearchForm, SpecimenForm
from projects.models import Project, Serie
from models import Specimen 
from tests.models import Test  ## Test importation!!
import simplejson
import json
from django.core import serializers
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
import datetime


def new_specimen(request, project_id=None, serie_id=None):
    ...
```

And my Test class in tests.models:

```
from django.db import models
from projects.models import Project
from specimens.models import Specimen
#from operator.models import Operator
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class Test(models.Model):

    ref         = models.CharField(max_length=70, unique=True)
    #name       = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True, blank=True, default='NULL')
    project     = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    specimen    = models.ForeignKey(Specimen)
    #operator   = models.ForeignKey(Operator)
    notes       = models.TextField(max_length=170, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=170, blank=True)
    start_date  = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    finish_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    status      = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True)
```

Would you need more information? Please, let me know if necessary. Any ideas of the problem? Could be that the name `tests` is a reserved word??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried to open your python shell and import `tests` module alone? If you are able to do that, then look for its path: `import tests;print tests.__file__`. Maybe it's not what you would expect.

Comment: You have circular dependency. You haven't shown enough of your code to know exactly where it is, but tests.models is importing projects.models and specimens.models and it's likely that one of those is importing tests.models, hence the import loop.

Comment: please check it: `python manage.py shell` . then `from tests.models import Test` . what it will return? it's ok or failed?

Answer (score 0):

It does look like an import loop, but I doubt you import `Test` model anywhere else. Don't use relative import in your view `from models import Specimen` it might be causing your problem. And don't put any models in your `tests.py` it should be used only for tests and you shouldn't need any test Models for your tests.